# Data management with python

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I have a question regarding a little python project im working on. Im trying to scrape data from a climbing webpage. They have listed different summits with different routes. For each route there are many comments of different users. So far the scraping itself works pretty good. Now Im trying to figure out a way to store the scraped information in an useful way.

1) Create a database with SQLite3

2) Object orientated programming with python

So far I think that the object orientated method may be the way to go. I would create a class for each route. This class then would contain of attributes for summit and user comments.

But is there a different or easiert method to do such things?

Greetings,

Martin

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'Object orientated programming with python' with regards storing the scraped data?

Comment: are you asking about an ORM (object relational mapper)? the two things you have referred to are largely independant

Comment: @ConorThompson: From my basic programming skills I thought, that object orientated had something to do with classes and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing apples and oranges here... [OO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) has nothing to do with data persistance, it's a (so-called) programming paradigm (like [procedural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_programming), [imperative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming), [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) programming etc). How and where you store your data and how and where you use them are orthogonal concerns. FWIW quite a few frameworks use a relational database for storage with an OO wrapper (called an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)) above.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to save your objects as they are, just pickle them. Not a solution for purists, but that is perhaps what you meant by "Object orientated programming with python"?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be asking about an ORM, which provides an abstraction over a database layer. 
this link provides an overview of what an ORM is: https://www.fullstackpython.com/object-relational-mappers-orms.html